# measuring ppp traffic with ifstat

Tags: networking, ppp, statistics, pppd

I've established a ppp link with 2 Linux machines. The speed is set to 9600. Traffic is going one way, i.e. from Machine 1 to Machine 2. However when I run `ifstat -btwTWS -i ppp0` on Machine 2, I'm getting a value of `12.09 Kbps` for `Kbps in`. How is this possible? Shouldn't the maximum value be 9.6 Kbps? What is going on?

Comment: It might be accounting for compression.  9.6k/sec _compressed_ could easily be ~15k/sec _uncompressed_

Comment: @DopeGhoti Is there a way to account for traffic without taking into account decompression?